# Match pattern only if enclosed in parentheses

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a few test cases:
Bad:

```
1 + 2
(3 + 4) + 5
(1 + 2) + (3 + 4)
```

Good:

```
(1 + 2)
((3 + 4) + 5)
((1 + 2) + (3 + 4))
```

I want a regex that matches anything inside parentheses. Basically, if there is anything outside of parentheses, its bad. You should assume the string is always right, so you dont have to count the starting and closing parentheses.

I tried doing the following: `^\(.*\)$`

This also matches `(1 + 2) + (6 + 7)` which is bad and I don't know how to do it beter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a regex with a [**subroutine call**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) that matches nested `(...)`  recursively:

```
^(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RXHbl5/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string (may be replaced with `\A`, to ensure matching start of string only)
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Capturing group 1 that will be recursed matching:

  - `\(` - a literal `(`
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of:

    - `[^()]++` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` (matched possessively to disallow backtracking into the pattern)
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - subroutine call that recurses Group 1 pattern
  - `\)` - a literal `)`
- `$` - end of string (to match the end of  a string, use `\Z`, or the very end of string can be matched with `\z`)

Note that `(?R)` construct cannot be used here since it would recurse the whole pattern, and the anchors (`^` and `$`) would fail all matches inside the string.

Comment: The best answer of the week award goes to you.

Comment: Beat my by a second, I should absolutely increase my typing speed.

Comment: There would be no harm in writing a longer answer with a character by character description of the regular expression.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Yes, I write my explanations by hand, and it takes time.